# Magento: Replace currency drop down menu with currency symbols to cklick on

Tags: magento, menu, selector, currency

We have a currency drop down selector in the top right of our header.
I would like to replace that with currency symbols to click on.
i.e.:

$   £   €

Answer (score 0):

Check this link. This may be helpful.

[Change currency dropdown](http://magento-talks.blogspot.in/2011/09/how-to-show-country-flag-in-magento.html)

[Currency symbol](http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/270821/)

[Currency selector](http://www.magentocommerce.com/answers/discussion/543/Adding-Currency-Symbol-to-currency-selector/p1)

If you dont want dropdown menu use this code in your themes "directory/currency.phtml"

```
<ul>
        <?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
        <li>
          <a onclick="setLocation('<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>')"><?php echo Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($_code)->getSymbol()?> - <?php echo $_code ?></a>
         </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
```

Comment: Thanks. However, what I am looking for is to replace the drop down menu with a row of text symbols to click on.

Comment: This is the one that you expected?

Answer (score 0):

In your Themes template/directory/currency.phtml change the code to this (this is based on the RWD theme):

```
<?php if($this->getCurrencyCount()>1): ?>
<div>
<ul class="in_currency">
<?php foreach ($this->getCurrencies() as $_code => $_name): ?>
<li style="float:left;padding:0px 5px 0px 0px;">
<a href="<?php echo $this->getSwitchCurrencyUrl($_code) ?>" onclick="setLocation(this.value);">
<?php echo $_code ?>
<?php
$currencySymbol = Mage::app()->getLocale()->currency($_code)->getSymbol();
?>
<?php //echo $currencySymbol; ?>

</a>
</li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>
</div>
```